# Pi reject ssh connect after pi idle an hour

Tags: ssh

i am new to pi, and i use it as webserver.
but every time i dc from ssh, after few hour connect again,
pi reject my connect, even use vnc or ssh.
what i can do is unplug my power to manual reboot. (truly hurt...)

and my pi using Ethernet network (just beside router), 
so i am sure not wifi power safe feature cause it.
also, my pi haven't plug any usb stick and using 32gb micro sd card as system disk. last, i am using 2v power with plug.

i google for this problem, and try to ping some website every 15min to keep network active, but unlucky, it's fail to save my pi.

i wish i got a solution from you guys,
thanks and please forgive my broken english :D

**Update** : i am using Pi2 and run with Raspbian Jessie, using LAMP as webserver

Ken

Comment: Try reverting back to last configuration where you did not have this issue.

Comment: hi @grepmaster , i just get my pi for few day only and i din't do any changing.

Comment: try checking in /var/log/syslog to see if there's any information that could be of any use

Comment: You haven't given us any information. What Pi? What OS? Hardware? How did you install webserver?

Comment: @Miliways, i am sorry to miss this information, it's Pi2 in raspbian Jessie. website install by command : apt-get install apache2

Answer (score 1):

I have a wifi adapter that is not reliable on the pi -- or was not, I don't use it there anymore, but when I was doing so I wrote this:

[How to automatically reconnect WiFi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5121/5538)

to make it check the internet connection at short intervals and reconnect if necessary.

Note that I've always disabled normal network autoconfiguration stuff which will probably interfere with that; there's an explanation of how to do that here:

[How can I disable autoconfigured networking on Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37594/how-can-i-disable-autoconfigured-networking-on-raspbian)

Also, in the script from the first link, I'm using an unencrypted network.  If you are using a more normal WPA WLAN then use the commands from the second link in place of the `iwconfig` and `dhclient` -- but do not put them in subshell parantheses and fork (the `( ... ) &`).