# RasPi 3 - wlan0 not associated

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3

I have two RasPi3, both on the newest Jessie and updated && upgraded. The problem is that both Pis can see networks but are not connecting to them.

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Gives me multiple networks including the one I want to connect to. Typing in the credentials and authentication into the wpa_supplicant.conf file doesn't work. Then I installed xrdp on the Pis to see if a connection over that is possible. Again I see available networks including the one I want to connect to. I click it, type in the requested key and nothing happens. Afterwards a mouseover on the networks button in the upper right corner shows "wlan0 not associated".

```
sudo ifup wlan0
```

tells me that the wlan0 interface is already configured. Makes sense. 
The newest firmware for the WiFi chip on the board is installed.

When I set the Pis up, they connected without any problems. Even to the same network as they should now. Nothing changed in the meantime.

What can I try?

EDIT:
Just tested to connect to my phone using the mobile hotspot. No problem at all...It gets confusing.

Comment: Have you tried (shock! horror!) the Foundation Guidelines https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md

Comment: They are useless as they tell me what I just described and I can't use `wpa_gui` anymore in the new raspbian jessie releases.

Comment: Then there is always [the dark side](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37594/how-can-i-disable-autoconfigured-networking-on-raspbian).  Presuming you have a correct `wpa_supplicant.conf`, it actually only takes two or three commands to manually connect, -- `ip link set wlan0 up` (maybe superfluous), `wpa_supplicant ...`, and `dhclient...`.  This may make it easier to figure out what's wrong, *but first you have to disable autoconfiguration, dhcpcd, etc.*.

Comment: Okay that has to wait until Wednesday. But thanks I will try all that.

Comment: Did you ever got it working?

Comment: Yes by using a WiFi dongle instead of the onboard WiFi. Disabled the onboard WiFi using a blacklist. Works perfectly fine. But couldn't find the reason why it was not working normally.

Comment: @goldilocks answer works like a charm on my Pi3.  `ip link set wlan0 up`.

Answer (score 7):

To work with`wpa_supplicant` on some routers and networks can be pretty tricky and hard to diagnose. Using the following method I have a 100% success rate.
First to confirm your network is available and visible try (just the SSID is enough):

```
  iwlist wlan0 scan | grep SSID
```

Then create a network credential entry for `supplicant` with:

```
wpa_passphrase "<ssid>" "<password>" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

<sup>*Note* ssid (and password) are case sensitive.</sup>

This will create a 64 char PSK as follows:

```
network={
        ssid="ssid"
        #psk="password"
        psk=44116ea881531996d8a23af58b376d70f196057429c258f529577a26e727ec1b
}
```

You may edit your .conf to remove (or '#' comment) the replaced network.

This network definition will be enough to associate/register. You don't need the usual parameters like:

```
proto=WPA WPA2
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK WPA-EAP
```

If this is not working, you can debug it running `supplicant` in debug mode, be a fast reader or use `^S`/`^Q` on your console to pause it:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B -D
```

If `wpa_supplicant` is running on `wlan0` you will receive the message:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
Failed to initialize control interface 'DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
```

Just kill the running version, in this example is process '651' (second column, after 'root'):

```
> ps aux | grep supplicant
root       651  0.0  0.7   7244  3516 ?        Ss   15:20   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
root      1651  0.0  0.4   4272  1844 pts/0    S+   16:35   0:00 /bin/grep --color supplicant
> kill 651
```

and try again.

Comment: Hello, first I tried with WEP network, so in my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file there was old WEP setting (even I rebooted RP3). I deleted old one, and it worked.

Comment: you saved my life trying to fix this from few days, thank you!