# Raspberry Pi Zero W can't connect to wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-zero-w, wpa-supplicant

I have been trying to setup a raspberry pi 0w to connect to my access point but I can't get it to connect. The first thing I did was to enable USB ethernet and make the ssh file so I can connect to it over SSH, I then used raspi-config to setup WiFi. After this, the RPi didn't have an IP under wlan0 as I expected. I then tried to use a wpa-supplicant file with my wifi password and SSID:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
 ssid="SSID"
 psk="pass"
 key_mgmt=WPA-PSK 
}
```

This didn't work after a reboot and using `ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0` didn't work either. I then removed the usb ethernet config changes on the SD card but still had no luck. After adding them back in and then changing the indentation to 0 spaces, 4 spaces, 1 space and a tab it still didn't work. I honestly I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

- SSID is correct
- Country is correct
- Password is correct
- Band is correct (2.4GHz)
- Line endings are correct

After reading this post: [Raspi doesn't connect with wifi anymore. What am I doing wrong?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98217/raspi-doesnt-connect-with-wifi-anymore-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

I followed the steps to manually start wpa_supplicant (`sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0`) and all I am getting is a status_code 16 error 4 times then an auth_faliures=1 error. I know for certain the password is correct. I really have no idea what to do next.

Comment: To exclude the obvious: Does GB match your country? Does `wpa_cli -i wlan0 scan` (wait a few seconds then) `wpa_cli -i wlan0 scan_results` show networks?

Comment: GB matches my country and I remember doing a scan with ifup (I think?) which definitely showed all the networks including the one I want to connect to.

Comment: [What's wrong with “I followed this tutorial” kind of questions?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/whats-wrong-with-i-followed-this-tutorial-kind-of-questions)

Comment: This question is lacking any detail. You mention "enable USB ethernet" without detail and used obsolete commands "ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0" . There is no evidence - the bare minimum in `ip a; ip r`.

Comment: Verify that capitalization in the SSID name matches exactly what was put in for the ssid="" value.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add key_mgmt if you're using WPA:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
    ssid="SSID"
    psk="pass"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK 
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've already tried that. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Raspberry Pi cannot connect to some Wi-Fi routers.**

It's a fact.

For example, my Raspberry Pi 3B and 3B+ cannot connect to my Linksys WAG200G although:

- These Rpi can connect to all other Wi-Fi I have (2 smartphone access points, main ISP router, friend routers), and,
- All other Wi-Fi enabled devices I have (2 smartphones, 2 company laptops, Nintendo Switch, Sony PlayStation 3, Pioneer Blu-ray player, iPad 3, all friend smartphones, etc.) can connect to the Linksys WAG200G.

**I had to plug RPi to WAG200G with an Ethernet cable.**

Try to access some other WIFI (smartphone access point, anything) to see if your problem is only with a specific router, like me.

Comment: This is very weird. My rpi 3 can connect to the WiFi just fine, and I have tried multiple WiFi routers.

Comment: Do you have a 3B or a 3B+?
You can use the `pinout` command to know.
I have researched info and it seems that **Zero W** and **3B** models use the same `BCM43438` chip for WiFi, while **3B+** model uses a `CYW43455`.
I am not sure and I don't know the specs of these, but it is what I found online.