# Wifi disabled after reconfiguring HDMI

Tags: wifi, hdmi, config.txt

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 A+ with Raspbian Stretch (updated/upgraded about a month ago), connected to a Manga Screen 2: http://wiki.thing-printer.com/index.php?title=Manga_Screen_2

I have used this Raspberry Pi with a 1920x1080 desktop monitor, and also with an 800x480 5" HDMI touchscreen, and it works flawlessly with both of those. I am able to get the screen to display correctly on the Manga Screen 2, and the touches register correctly, but after setting config.txt and making a .rules file the wifi is magically disabled and I am out of ideas.

My config.txt is unmodified except for the hdmi configuration that the wiki for this screen specifies. wpa_supplicant contains the correct information, since it is unchanged and was working with a different screen just a few hours ago.

When I scan for wireless networks with iwlist wlan0 scan, I am able to see all the ones I should, including the one it was connected to before I switched screens. However, hovering over the wifi icon shows "wlan0 not associated" and ifup wlan0 tells me "unknown interface wlan0."

This fix did nothing: [RasPi 3 - wlan0 not associated](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50967/raspi-3-wlan0-not-associated)

I have tried 4 different Raspberry Pi 3 A+'s, as well as 3 different power supplies, and nothing has made a difference yet.

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks.

Edit 1: I believe the problem is caused by this line in config.txt:

`hdmi_timings=1080 1 100 10 60 1920 1 4 2 4 0 0 0 60 0 144000000 3`

When I comment out my changes to config.txt and connect the pi to an external monitor, the wifi connects with absolutely no issue. I need to read more about what that line actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm not sure why exactly this was causing an issue or why this is the fix, but I successfully restored my wifi connection. If anyone knows why this bug exists, I would love to know.

The line `hdmi_timings=1080 1 100 10 60 1920 1 4 2 4 0 0 0 60 0 144000000 3`, paired with `hdmi_mode=87` allows the user to specify a custom HDMI connection. The parameter of concern here is the pixel_freq or pixel clock frequency (the second to last number), which the manufacturer says to use 144 MHz (144000000). Official Raspberry Pi documentation says that this number should be `horizontal resolution * vertical resolution * refresh rate`, which is 1920x1080x60 for me. This comes out to **124416000**, not 144 MHz even.

Replacing the 144 MHz value with my number restored the wifi connection:

`hdmi_timings=1080 1 100 10 60 1920 1 4 2 4 0 0 0 60 0 124416000 3`

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.