# How do you bridge your wlan0 to your eth0?

Tags: ethernet, connection, wifi

I'm trying to bridge the wlan interface of my Pi with the ethernet port. I found [this](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnectionsProxyArp) tutorial that shows how to do this on Debian - but I'm unable to get it working. I'm quite a layman on Linux and networking, all I want is to be able to connect to my wlan and then connect another computer to the ethernet port and have internet (and be in the same network), optimally while still being able to access my Pi via SSH.

Whenever I reboot I get "deconfiguring netowrk settings...", I think that might be part of the problem. I have seen [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37594/how-can-i-disable-autoconfigured-networking-on-raspbian) thread that explains how to disable this, but it seems quite daunting and I want to be sure that this could solve my problem before I try it.

Maybe I also didn't understand the tutorial correctly; it uses terms like "primery LAN network [IP] adress" which I couldn't decifer with Google and just assumed to be the IP adress if my router.