# WiFi Hotspot is not working with LAN and wifi configuration in interfaces

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have setup a Wifi Hotspot using Edimax WiFi Dongle. The Hotspot is working without the eth0 configuration.

```
auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
    #wireless
    auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.9.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    #end wireless
```

I can connect to SSID and ping to 192.168.9.1. Its working well. I am using Static LAN cable connection when not using the WiFi hotspot.So I changed my configuration to

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#wired
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.9.104
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 0.0.0.0
#end wired

#wireless
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.9.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
#end wireless
```

Now my hotspot is not working. I can connect to SSID but unable to ping to the IP 192.168.9.1. How I can keep the static IP configuration for LAN and hotspot in the configuration.

Following is the list configuration I done in my system
My **dhcpd.cof** contain

```
    #
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd for Debian
#
#

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-update-style none;

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "example.org";
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
#authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;

# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the 
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.

#subnet 10.152.187.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#}

# This is a very basic subnet declaration.

#subnet 192.168.9.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#  range 192.168.9.201 192.168.9.250;
#  option routers 192.168.9.104;
 # option broadcast-address 192.168.9.255;
#}


subnet 192.168.9.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.9.100 192.168.9.200; 
  option domain-name "MyWifi";
}

# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
#subnet 10.5.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range 10.5.5.26 10.5.5.30;
#  option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;
#  option domain-name "internal.example.org";
#  option routers 10.5.5.1;
#  option broadcast-address 10.5.5.31;
#  default-lease-time 600;
#  max-lease-time 7200;
#}

# Hosts which require special configuration options can be listed in
# host statements.   If no address is specified, the address will be
# allocated dynamically (if possible), but the host-specific information
# will still come from the host declaration.

#host passacaglia {
#  hardware ethernet 0:0:c0:5d:bd:95;
#  filename "vmunix.passacaglia";
#  server-name "toccata.fugue.com";
#}

# Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.   These addresses
# should not also be listed as being available for dynamic assignment.
# Hosts for which fixed IP addresses have been specified can boot using
# BOOTP or DHCP.   Hosts for which no fixed address is specified can only
# be booted with DHCP, unless there is an address range on the subnet
# to which a BOOTP client is connected which has the dynamic-bootp flag
# set.
#host fantasia {
#  hardware ethernet 08:00:07:26:c0:a5;
#  fixed-address fantasia.fugue.com;
#}

# You can declare a class of clients and then do address allocation
# based on that.   The example below shows a case where all clients
# in a certain class get addresses on the 10.17.224/24 subnet, and all
# other clients get addresses on the 10.0.29/24 subnet.

#class "foo" {
#  match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 4) = "SUNW";
#}

#shared-network 224-29 {
#  subnet 10.17.224.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-224.example.org;
#  }
#  subnet 10.0.29.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-29.example.org;
#  }
#  pool {
#    allow members of "foo";
#    range 10.17.224.10 10.17.224.250;
#  }
#  pool {
#    deny members of "foo";
#    range 10.0.29.10 10.0.29.230;
#  }
#}
```

**hostapd** contain

```
# Defaults for hostapd initscript
#
# See /usr/share/doc/hostapd/README.Debian for information about alternative
# methods of managing hostapd.
#
# Uncomment and set DAEMON_CONF to the absolute path of a hostapd configuration
# file and hostapd will be started during system boot. An example configuration
# file can be found at /usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf.gz
#
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"

# Additional daemon options to be appended to hostapd command:-
#   -d   show more debug messages (-dd for even more)
#   -K   include key data in debug messages
#   -t   include timestamps in some debug messages
#
# Note that -B (daemon mode) and -P (pidfile) options are automatically
# configured by the init.d script and must not be added to DAEMON_OPTS.
#
#DAEMON_OPTS=""
```

**hostapd.conf** contains

```
interface=wlan0
driver=rtl871xdrv
bridge=br0
ssid=MyWifi 4600/1500
channel=1
wmm_enabled=0
wpa=1
wpa_passphrase=secretpass
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0
```

Comment: What version of Raspbian are you running.

Comment: Linux version 3.18.11-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140303 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2650 - Linaro GCC 2014.03) ) #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015

Comment: Is it related to the raspbian version.

Comment: Only indirectly related (it is rather difficult to work out which version is installed). From the kernel version it appears to be between Feb and May 2015. Later versions are configured differently, particularly wrt internet. How have you "setup a Wifi Hotspot"?

Comment: I have updated my question with the configuration details. and I used this tutorial to setup Edimax wifi in my raspberry PI http://www.daveconroy.com/turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-hotspot-with-edimax-nano-usb-ew-7811un-rtl8188cus-chipset/

Comment: Raspbian version can be found w/ `cat /etc/issue` (it's either 7 or 8).  You might want to have a look at this one: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/9678/5538